# How to position the cursor at the beginning of the mask when pushing tab key?

Tags: javascript, forms, mask

In the form in the phone field, I use a mask based on the [Imask library](https://imask.js.org/guide.html).

1. I am trying to make it when focusing with both the mouse or the tab on the field, a full mask with brackets appears, and the cursor is set to the initial input position. There is a problem here: either an incomplete mask appears, or only +38, or the cursor moves to the end due to a taboo on the field.
2. I can't clear the phone field after submitting the form, I get warning:

> Element value was changed outside of mask. Syncronize mask using
> mask.updateValue() to work properly.

```js
const phone = document.querySelector('.phone');
const name = document.querySelector('.name');
const form = document.querySelector('#form');

if (phone) {
  phone.onfocus = () => {
    newIMask(phone)
  }

  form.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.key == 'Tab') {
      if (phone.value === '') {
        let tabMask = IMask(
          phone, {
            mask: '+38( 000) 000-00-00',
            lazy: false
          });
      }
    }
  });
}

function newIMask(phone) {
  let phoneMask = IMask(
    phone, {
      mask: '{+38} (000) 000-00-00',
      lazy: false
    });
  phone.value = phoneMask.unmaskedValue; //если закомментировать, то по табу курсор сместиться вконец
}

document.getElementById("form").addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  phone.value = "";
  window.open('mailto:mail@example.com?name=' + name.value + '&body=' + phone.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imask"></script>
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" name="name" class="name">
  <input type="tel" name="phone" class="phone">
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
  <form>
```

**UPD**
With this insertion of the code, I sort of solve the issue with the tab

```
const form = document.querySelector('#form');
    form.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
      if(e.key == 'Tab') {
        if(phone.value === '') {
          let tabMask = IMask(
            phone, {
              mask: '+38( 000) 000-00-00',
              lazy: false
          });
        }
      }
    });
```

but each digit is entered with a warring:

> Warring: Element value was changed outside of mask. Syncronize mask
> using mask.updateValue() to work properly.

and the phone field is not cleared when sending.

Could you help me with finding the right solution?

Comment: First, I misunderstood the title. "Switching tabs" - I thought browser tabs and not the `TAB` key.
If I understand correctly, you want the cursor to appear before the "+38" when it first fets the focus and even when the phone input is focused later after a tab key switch.

Firstly, this `mask.updateValue()` method is not even mentioned in the docs!.
However, there are several issues on the plugin's Github page  regarding this console warning here: https://github.com/uNmAnNeR/imaskjs/issues?q=updateValue
I would recommend checking these as well.

Comment: @ZR87 yes, thank you for your correction  - I definitely mean pushing the `TAB` key. English isn't my mother language, so I made a mistake. But, I can't find solution by the link to faq you gived to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning happens because you need to configure the Imask and inside the configuration have functions which catch input value.

> Use prepare (value, masked) option for preprocessing input and commit
> (value, masked) option for postprocessing after UI is deactivated

And for work correctly need only to use *mask.updateOptions*  to update options.

```js
  const phone = document.querySelector('.phone');
  const name = document.querySelector('.name');
  const form = document.getElementById('form');

  const maskOptions = {
    mask: '',
    lazy: false,
    placeholderChar: '#',
    overwrite: true,
    prepare: value => value, // onChange event
    commit: value => (phone.value = value), // set value to phone number
  };

  // Init IMask
  const mask = IMask(phone, maskOptions);

  if (phone) {
    form.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
      if (e.key == 'Tab') {
        // Update options "mask" after pressed Tab key
        mask.updateOptions({
          mask: '{+38}(000)000-00-00',
        });
      }
    });
  }

  phone.addEventListener('focus', () => {
    // Update options "mask" after focused
    mask.updateOptions({
      mask: '{+38}(000)000-00-00',
    });
  });

  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('sending phone number ', phone.value);

    // Update options & clear up values after submit form
    mask.updateOptions({
      mask: '',
      commit: (value, masked) => {
        value = '';
        masked._value = '';
      },
    });

    phone.blur();
    name.value = '';

    window.open(
      'mailto:mail@example.com?name=' + name.value + '&body=' + phone.value
    );
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imask"></script>
    <form id="form">
      <input type="text" name="name" class="name" >
      <input type="tel" name="phone" class="phone">
      <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
      <form>
```